# Adobe PDF API extract on Databricks

Tags: pdf, adobe, databricks, adobe-pdfservices

I'm trying to setup the sample code used for pdf data extract using the python sdk for Adobe PDF API service on a databricks environment. This cluster has just one driver node. But i'm facing issue while accessing the configuration files uploaded to DBFS folder.

Please let me know how do i fix the issue.

Here is the code snippet

```
import logging
import os.path

from adobe.pdfservices.operation.auth.credentials import Credentials
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.exception.exceptions import ServiceApiException, ServiceUsageException, SdkException
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_pdf_options import ExtractPDFOptions
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_element_type import ExtractElementType
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_renditions_element_type import \
    ExtractRenditionsElementType
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.table_structure_type import TableStructureType
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.execution_context import ExecutionContext
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.io.file_ref import FileRef
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.extract_pdf_operation import ExtractPDFOperation

#logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO"))


credentials = Credentials.service_account_credentials_builder() \
    .from_file("/dbfs/FileStore/pdfservices_api_credentials.json") \
    .build()

execution_context = ExecutionContext.create(credentials)
extract_pdf_operation = ExtractPDFOperation.create_new()

source = FileRef.create_from_local_file("/dbfs/FileStore/form.pdf")
extract_pdf_operation.set_input(source)

# Build ExtractPDF options and set them into the operation
extract_pdf_options: ExtractPDFOptions = ExtractPDFOptions.builder() \
    .with_elements_to_extract([ExtractElementType.TEXT, ExtractElementType.TABLES]) \
    .with_element_to_extract_renditions(ExtractRenditionsElementType.TABLES) \
    .with_table_structure_format(TableStructureType.CSV) \
    .build()
extract_pdf_operation.set_options(extract_pdf_options)

# Execute the operation.
result: FileRef = extract_pdf_operation.execute(execution_context)

result.save_as(base_path + "/output/ExtractTextInfoFromPDF.zip")
```

Here is the error details:

```
INFO:adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.extract_pdf_operation:All validations successfully done. Beginning ExtractPDF operation execution
INFO:py4j.java_gateway:Received command c on object id p0
INFO:py4j.java_gateway:Received command c on object id p0
INFO:py4j.java_gateway:Received command c on object id p0
INFO:py4j.java_gateway:Received command c on object id p0
SdkException: description =Exception in fetching access token, requestTrackingId=(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'get'"), <traceback object at 0x7f7572a3fd00>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-150d96ca-003d-4671-a6d9-ab8e566616d1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/internal/auth/jwt_authenticator.py in refresh_token(self)
     62                                        data=access_token_request_payload, headers={})
---> 63             response = http_client.process_request(http_request=http_request, success_status_codes=[HTTPStatus.OK],
     64                                                    error_response_handler=self.handle_ims_failure)

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-150d96ca-003d-4671-a6d9-ab8e566616d1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/internal/http/http_client.py in process_request(http_request, success_status_codes, error_response_handler)
     37         response = _execute_request(http_request)
---> 38         if _handle_response_and_retry(response, success_status_codes,
     39                                       error_response_handler, not http_request.authenticator, http_request.request_key) and http_request.retryable:

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-150d96ca-003d-4671-a6d9-ab8e566616d1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/internal/http/http_client.py in _handle_response_and_retry(response, success_status_codes, error_response_handler, is_ims_api, request_key)
     94             "Failure response code {error_code} encountered from backend".format(error_code=response.status_code))
---> 95         should_retry = ResponseUtil.handle_api_failures(response, request_key, is_ims_api)
     96         return should_retry if should_retry else error_response_handler(response)
```

Comment: image is too small to see error message - post the code & error message as text, not as image

Comment: i have added the code and error details

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing forward slash in the file name, so the file is considered as path relative to the current directory `/databricks/driver/`. Instead of `dbfs/tmp/pdf/pdfservices-api-credentials.json` try `/dbfs/tmp/pdf/pdfservices-api-credentials.json`.

Update for community edition: There is no support for `/dbfs` mount on the community edition, so you need to copy file from DBFS to the local file system for use. You can do it using `dbutils.fs.cp` command:

```py
# copy file to local disk
dbutils.fs.cp("/tmp/pdf/pdfservices-api-credentials.json",
  "file:/tmp/pdfservices-api-credentials.json")
# use it
credentials = Credentials.service_account_credentials_builder() \
        .from_file("/tmp/pdfservices-api-credentials.json") \
        .build()
```

Comment: Its not working. I'm still getting the same error type:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/tmp/pdf/pdfservices-api-credentials.json'

Comment: where the file is stored? Are you using community edition or full Databricks?

Comment: Its a community edition i'm using and files i have placed in DBFS location

Comment: updated for community edition

Comment: i'm not using any community edition anymore, created a databricks cluster and now getting a new error.